# Got wrong stemming using Porter, Lancaster, and SnowballStemmer

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp

I took this sentence from news articles randomly, and I am trying to stem using Porter, Lancaster and SnowballStemmer. I find these observations as shown in the outputs below (wrong stem). I used the same method for SnowballStemmer and Porter.

```
ds = "happiness john mccain furious iran treated us say justice yahoo settles email privacy said classactiosunnistan us said allied safe zone plan take territ blow million al jazeera america finally calls us navy sailors held iranian military signs n"
```

```
stemmer = PorterStemmer()

def porter_stem_words(word):
    word = word.split()
    word = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in word]
    word = ' '.join(word)
    return word
stemmed_words = porter_stem_words(ds)
print(stemmed_words)
```

```
lancaster_stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

temp_rule_list = list(lancaster_stemmer._rule_tuple)
lancaster_stemmer._rule_tuple.index('e1>') 
temp_rule_list.pop(12)
lancaster_stemmer._rule_tuple = tuple(temp_rule_list)

def lancaster_stem_words(word):
    word = word.split()
    word = [lancaster_stemmer.stem(word) for word in word]
    word = ' '.join(word)
    return word
stemmed_words = lancaster_stem_words(ds2)
print(stemmed_words)
```

The PorterStemmer output is:

> happi john mccain furiou iran treat us say justic yahoo settl email privaci said classactiosunnistan us said alli safe zone plan take territ blow million al jazeera america final call us navi sailor held iranian militari sign n

SnowballStemmer output is:

> happi mcpain john mccain furious iran treat us sai justic yahoo settl email privaci classactiosunnistan us alli safe zone plan take territ blow million al jazeera america final call us navi sailor held iranian militari sign n

LancasterStemmer output:

> happy mcpain john mccain fury ir tre us sai justice yahoo settle email priv classactiosun us al safe zone plan take territ blow mil al jazeer americ fin cal us navy sail held ir milit sign n

I am not able to understand these concepts. Could you please help? I already look at (https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/stem/lancaster.py#L62)
I am trying to find the root of the words in a big dataset, and I noticed that the stemming cut the words in a wrong way, such as:
Input: happiness
Porter: happi
Snowball: happi
Lancaster: happy

Input: iran
Porter: iran
Snowball: iran
Lancaster: ir

Input: furious
Porter: furiou
Snowball: furious
Lancaster: fury

Input: million
Porter: million
Snowball: million
Lancaster: mil

Answer (score 0):

The Porter algorithm is injective: it transforms from a large space of words to a smaller space of word prefixes. Multiple words, and inflections of those words, map to the same prefix. Settlement, setttler, settles, all map to "settl", for example.

The other algorithms do similar things.

The point is to allow search features in programs to get some fuzziness. Like soundex and megaphone algorithms, these stemming algorithms allow search engines to cast a wide net for matching items. To be most useful, a program should present to the human user a bunch of possibly-matching search results and let the human pick relevant ones. Lots of false positive matches with these algorithms. But that's their point.

Comment: I understood your answer, but I'm trying to use it on a big dataset. So, it is impossible to have humans pick relevant ones. In this case, how can I solve this issue?